# Finding the uncertainty from a probability distribution?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, probability, commutator

If you have two properties, $A$ and $B$, that do not commute, and thus have a commutator $C$, and the uncertainties $\Delta A$ and $\Delta B$ obey the relation $$(\Delta A)(\Delta B)\geq \frac{1}{2}|C|$$

If you know the exact form of the probability distribution of $A$, could you use this to find the uncertainty $\Delta A$?

Continuing along the same train of thought, could you employ the same process in reverse, to obtain the probability distribution of $B$, either approximate or exact, through the relation $(\Delta A)(\Delta B)\geq \frac{1}{2}|C|$ if the uncertainty of $A$ can be found?

Answer (score 1):

> If you know the exact form of the probability distribution of $A$, could you use this to find the uncertainty $dA$?

I'm not sure what you mean by "probability distribution of $A$". $A$ is an *operator*: it operates on some state $|\psi\rangle$ and gives us something back. We can only talk about the probability distribution of $|\psi\rangle$ (in some basis, like $\psi(x)$), in which case $dA$ can be found as
$$\Delta A = \sqrt{\langle\psi|A^2|\psi\rangle - \langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle^2}.$$

> Continuing along the same train of thought, could you employ the same process in reverse, to obtain the probability distribution of B, either approximate or exact, through the relation (dA)(dB)>=(1/2)|C| if the uncertainty of A can be found?

No, we can't really say much about the probability distribution. All we can work with is the standard deviation, which is a single number which describes some very general properties of a distribution.

Comment: actually yours isn’t right either.  There is *certainly* the square of an absolute value; see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson%E2%80%93Schr%C3%B6dinger_uncertainty_relations